# How to filter in dropdown lists in filemaker pro 15

Tags: database, forms, filter, filemaker

I've been searching a lot for this. I do not want a drill down filter where I start with 1 dropdownand narrow down in the other based on one choice. No, I want to filter on 1 specific database field.

An example:

I have 1 table Companies. In that table I have a FK to CompanyType (ex. Supplier, Customer, ...)

In my invoices Form I want to have a dropdown from my Companies table with only the Customers in. (so, for example, dropdown where CustomerTypeID = 1)

In my Expenses Form I want to have a dropdown from my Companies table with only the Suppliers in. (so, for example, dropdown where CustomerTypeID = 2)

Thoughts? Many thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my invoices Form I want to have a dropdown from my Companies table
>   with only the Customers in. (so, for example, dropdown where
>   CustomerTypeID = 1)

1. In your `Invoices` table, define an unstored calculation field
   `cConstant1` (result is Number) and enter:

   ```
   1
   ```

   as the formula.
2. Define a relationship between `Invoices` and a new occurrence of the
   `Companies` table (let's name it `Customers`) as:

   ```
   Invoices::cConstant1 = Customers::CustomerTypeID
   ```
3. Define your value list to use values from `Customers::CompanyID`, include only related values starting from `Invoices`.

---

Alternatively, define a calculation field named `cCustomerID` in the Companies table =

```
If ( CustomerTypeID = 1 ; CompanyID )
```

and define your value list to use this field.